# Why different translation units do not have independent & sandboxed memory spaces?

Tags: c++

I got struck by a segfault in my code where I was just doing the following:

```
std::vector<int> A;
A.push_back(2);
```

After wasting too much time trying to figure out what was the issue in my code (even valgrind was crashing), I found that a library that I was using (in its own translation unit), was accessing and editing an element of a vector out of its bounds.

Is there any mitigation for these issues? Or we can only pray that the libraries we are using will not leak?
Why different translation units are allowed to share memory space?

Comment: "Or we can only pray that the libraries we are using will not leak? " - well, praying is a waste of time - but if you use widely-used, well-tested libraries, this should not be a major problem. Translation units need to share memory because that's the C and C++  memory model.

Comment: Well if they did, they wouldn't be very useful, right? How would you pass it any data? And how would you receive them back?

Comment: All of the memory allocations should happen in the memory address assigned to a specific translation unit (in the one that the non pod type is defined). Accessing from other units should happen via pointers. Under any circumstance the memory spaces of two translation units should overlap.

Comment: If you want to improve/redesign C++, I'm afraid you are in a very, very wrong place. OTOH if you want to aak how to avoid a certain kind of programming error, please show code that actually has this error.

Comment: A library can be in principle be distributed in a binary form. You cannot always look into or present the source code in SO. And this is the major issue that bothers me. If the maintainer of the library is accessing out of bounds and messing with YOUR code you will probably never figure out, until you see it in production code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why different translation units do not have independent & sandboxed memory spaces?

Because it is extremely useful to be able to access data structures of one TU from another.

> Or we can only pray that the libraries we are using will not leak?

Well, leaking is one problem. Accessing memory out of bounds is usually a much more serious problem.

You can do more than pray. You can write (unit,integration,etc.) tests for the library and execute those with tools which attempt to detect undefined behaviour. Or, you can attempt to verify the correctness of the library by analysing the source manually.

If you cannot test a piece of code beforehand, such as in the case of third party plugins for example, there is a useful tool for memory segregation provided by (most?) operating systems: Processes. One process cannot directly access the memory of another process, so if you run the third party code in a subprocess, then it cannot corrupt the memory of the parent process, and if the child attempts a bad memory access, and is killed by the OS, the parent process need not be killed.

Unofortunately however, the C++ standard library has no API for processes.